# Ranging iBeacons in the background

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I am working on some internal location tracking, just to see how accurate it can get (not very).  The app is never going on the app store

Can I just check I have done everything to enable background iBeacons updates (didRangeBeacons) to happen, it does seem to work but die 20 mins later.  This could be useful to others as there seemed mixed info out there.

I am using iOS 9

1. Enable location updates in Capabilities
2. On each region enable region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
3. On Location Manager enable locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates
4. locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers (set this to save battery
5. Implement didUpdateLocations delegate method but you don't need to do anything here
6. I also implemented didUpdateToLocation delegate method just for belts and braces
7. Make sure you have the pList entries for Location Manager (NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription, NSLocationWhenInUseDescription)

Comment: You can only range in the background for a limited time. http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html

Comment: To add to what Paulw11 says above, I have found you can range for an unlimited amount of time if you set the location background mode as described and add a background thread per http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html